# How to get the Java version in PowerShell

Tags: java, powershell, version

I'm trying to get the Java version in PowerShell. The version string is printed to **stderr**, so I'm trying to redirect it to stdout and assign it to a string variable.

I get the following strange error:

```
PS P:\> & java -version 2>&1
java.exe : java version "1.7.0_25"
At line:1 char:2
+ & <<<<  java -version 2>&1
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (java version "1.7.0_25":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Call without redirection (2>&1) gives this:

```
PS P:\> & java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

I think that Java here is irrelevant, and the same would happen for any other program printing strings to stderr.

The PowerShell version I use is **2.0**.

**Questions:**

- How can I redirect stderr to a variable?
- Or, alternatively, how can I check the installed Java version?

**Workaround**

I can run it like this:

```
$output = & cmd /c "java -version 2>&1"
```

But I hate running a cmd.exe where it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way is using [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation):

```
$javaver =  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name like 'Java(TM)%'" | Select -Expand Version
```

Another one is redirect to a file with start-process:

```
start-process  java  -ArgumentList "-version" -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardError .\javaver.txt

$javaver = gc .\javaver.txt

del .\javaver.txt
```

And my last is:

```
dir "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"  | select -expa pschildname -Last 1
```

Regarding how redirect stderr in this case you can do:

```
$out = &"java.exe" -version 2>&1
$out[0].tostring()
```

Comment: Good approach! Didn't work for me just like this (something to do with the -Filter), but has worked as: Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name.StartsWith('Java')} | Select -Expand Version

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I knew about -RedirectStandardError option of Start-Process, but hate creating a file just for this simple reason...

Comment: @Ivan Added my last ;)

Comment: Amazing! Couldn't think there are so many ways of getting Java version. Will probably use the one with Get-WmiObject. Though it's still not clear how to redirect stderr in PS... but many thanks C.B.!

Comment: @Ivan Glad to help! I've added a method for redirect stderr, hope you like it

Comment: The `Get-WmiObject` approach just causes my script to hang, how annoying

Comment: Querying the Win32_Product for anything is not recommended.  Will cause a system to basically touch every single app installed via msi on a computer.

Answer (score 20):

I have been using `Get-Command` to get Java version on PowerShell 5.1.

```
Get-Command java | Select-Object Version
```

This returns an object. If you want a string instead, use:

```
(Get-Command java | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version).toString()
```

The outputs look like this:

```
PS > Get-Command java | Select-Object Version

Version
-------
8.0.1710.11



PS > Get-Command java | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
8      0      1710   11



PS > (Get-Command java | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version).tostring()
8.0.1710.11
```

It worked quite well under PowerShell 5.1. I don't have a chance to test this on PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: This works great, but be aware that the version will be reported as (e.g.) `8.0.910.14` by this method, whereas `java -version` reports `1.8.0_91`

Comment: This is 100X better than the marked answer.