# chef windows_package guards exists?

Tags: windows, powershell, chef-infra, guard

I have a `windows_package` resource that installs jdk 8 on a windows machine and it looks like this:

```
java_source="C:\\chef_solo\\utils\\jdk-8u121-windows-x64.exe"
package_name="Java(TM) SE Development Kit 8 (64-bit)"
windows_package package_name do
  source java_source
  action :install
  installer_type :custom
  options "/s #{additional_options}"
end
```

The problem is that every chef run, it install the same jdk and after the 2nd installation, java is not working anymore.

I was looking for `windows_package` guards, but couldn't find any. That's because they do not exists?

Anyway, I've found some powershell solutions that check if java exists and I need to know if I can use them somehow as a guard for my `windows_package` installation.

The solutions are here:
[How to get the Java version in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890926/how-to-get-the-java-version-in-powershell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guard clauses are a core feature available on all resources, so there is nothing specific to `windows_package` to find. You can find detailed info on `not_if`, `only_if`, and `guard_interpreter` in the Chef docs.

Answer (score 1):

So, following @coderanger 's idea, The final result is this one:

```
windows_package package_name do
  source java_source
  action :install
  installer_type :custom
  options "/s #{additional_options}"
  guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  only_if "!(dir 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment'  | select -expa pschildname -Last 1)"
end
```

If you have a better solution, please let me know.

Thank you.